# First define a polynonial(As a function), and then substitude with a matrix and have some problem in product

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to define a polynomial such as $f(x)=x^4+2x^3-4$, and want to substitude $x$ with the matrix $A$ into the polynomial. But I find the $A^4$ just work like $A.^4$ and not the correct $A^4$. How could I find some way to substitude and get a correct result?

Thanks for the comment, my code is as follows:

`A=[2 0 3 1;4 5 3 3;1 0 0 1;2 3 4 5];
 syms x;
 f=x^4+2*x^2-4;
 polyval(f,A)`

Comment: Please share your code, so we understand what you're doing and why `A^4` is not a matrix power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want Matrix polynomial evaluation. So you should polyvalm(). not polyval().
How to use it.

```
A=[2 0 3 1;4 5 3 3;1 0 0 1;2 3 4 5];
 syms x;
f=[1 0 2 0 -4] % x^4+2*x^2-4;
 polyvalm(f,A)
```